# Prove that there are infinitely many distinct natural numbers $a,b$ for which $\sqrt{a+b}, \sqrt{a-b}$ are simultaneously rational

Tags: rational-numbers, square-numbers, radical-equations

**the question**

Prove that there are infinitely many distinct natural numbers $a,b$ for which $\sqrt{a+b}, \sqrt{a-b}$ are simultaneously rational.

**the idea**

A radical is rational only if the number below it is a square number.  This means that for both of them to be simultaneously rational we get

$$a+b=x^2, a-b=y^2$$

From here I tried to take these two to a more general form that would lead us to infinitely many possibilities, but didn't get anything useful.

I hope one of you can help me!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are infinitely many odd squares $x^2$ and $y^2$ with $x>y>0$.

Let $a=\dfrac{x^2+y^2}2$ and $b=\dfrac{x^2-y^2}2$.

Comment: You can also have even squares, you just need same parity

Comment: I agree @DS, though my answer suffices

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you so much for you idea. Let me ask a question. So is enough to say that a and b can take those form and x and y can be any number to show there is an infinity of values for a and b?

Comment: There are infinitely many odd squares $(x^2,y^2)$, and distinct $(x^2,y^2)$ pairs correspond to distinct $(a,b)$ pairs, so there are infinitely many $(a,b)$ pairs